# Jssor slider not pausing and sterilizing anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, jssor

I've been working with the Jssor slider on a website I'm building. It's the first time using it and I'm running into two problems:

1) The slider appears to be sterilizing `<a>` tags within the slider `<div>`, removing any in-line styling and rendering the `<a>` tags un-clickable. It also appears to be pushing the tag *above* and outside of the slider itself. I've tried going into the browser developer settings and changing the code live, but the anchor is still broken

2) Setting the `$PauseOnHover`option to 1 does not stop the slider from autoplaying on hover.

Here is my current code block on my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $PauseOnHover: 1,
            $PlayOrientation: 1,
            $AutoPlayInterval: 6000,
            $SlideDuration: 850,
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("homeslide_container", options);
    });
</script>

        <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
        <div id="homeslide_container" style="position: relative; width: 944px; height: 325px;">

            <!-- Loading Screen -->
            <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
                <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                    background-color: #000000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
                </div>
                <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(../images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                    top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Slides Container -->
            <div u="slides" style="float:left; width:765px;height:332px; overflow: hidden;">       
                <!-- SLIDE ONE -->
                <div>
                    <a href="schooldesigns.html">
                        <img u="image" src="images/slider/slider4.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;height:100%;width:100%;z-index:-2;" />
                        <p style="font-size:2em; color:#fec30f;text-align:left;margin:15px 55px 0px 55px;text-shadow: 2px 2px black;">
                            Welcome
                        </p>
                        <p style="font-size:3.6em; font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; color:#e9e9f3;text-align:left;margin:0px 55px;text-shadow: 3px 3px black;">
                            Class of 2016
                        </p>
                        <p style="color:#afafaf; background-color:black; position:absolute; width:100%; bottom:0px; text-transform: uppercase; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:1em; padding:2px; letter-spacing: 4px; text-shadow: 1px 1px #444444;">
                        Brand new class list shirt designs and more    
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- SLIDE TWO -->
                <div>
                    <a href="gameday.html" style="position:absolute;top:0;">
                        <img u="image" src="../images/slider/slider2.jpg" style="height:100%;width:100%;z-index:-2;" />
                        <p style="font-size:3.6em; font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif; color:#e9e9f3;text-align:left;margin:0px 55px;text-shadow: 3px 3px black;">
                            GAME ON!
                        </p>
                        <p style="font-size:2em; color:#fec30f;text-align:left;margin:15px 55px 0px 55px;text-shadow: 2px 2px black;">
                            Bold Designs &amp; Game Jerseys
                        </p>
                        <p style="color:#afafaf; background-color:black; position:absolute; width:100%; bottom:0px; text-transform: uppercase; font-family:'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:1em; padding:2px; letter-spacing: 4px; text-shadow: 1px 1px #444444;">
                            Oversized fit for maximum comfort
                        </p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- SLIDE THREE -->
                <div>
                    <img u="image" src="../images/slider/slider3.jpg" style="width:708px"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p id="main_desc" style="height:292px; width:141px; float:right; clear:both;text-align:left; margin:0px;box-shadow:none;">Welcome to <b style="color:#00a1e4">WEBSITE</b>! Specialists in custom apparel for your 2016 senior class. <br><br>Website brings you customizable designs for your Senior, Junior, Sophomore and Freshman classes, school clubs, and sports teams!</p>
        </div>

        <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace

```
<img u="image" src="images/slider/slider4.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0;height:100%;width:100%;z-index:-2;" />
```

with

```
<img u="image" src="images/slider/slider4.jpg" />
```

Btw, the `$PauseOnHover: 1` should work. Please double check it, download the latest version if necessary.

Comment: replaced the style as you suggested, and updated to the latest version. I also removed all other html code within the div, so now my code is:
                        `<div>
                        <a u="image" href="schooldesigns.html">
                            <img u="image" src="images/slider/slider1.jpg" />
                        </a>
                   </div>`
Still does nothing

Answer (score 0):

Solved: My CSS had set the container to a z-index of -10. Removing the z-index instantly solved all issues.